# The log of a Moment Generating Function

Tags: self-study, moment-generating-function

I am having trouble understanding the rationale of the following related to the MGF:

Function Mx(t)=E[exp(tX)], the expectation exists for all t in a neighbourhood of zero, and X has mean mx,
show that
（1）logMx(t)/t>=mx for t>0
(2) the above inequality becomes equality as t tends to 0.

Here is what I have so far:
For (1), I applied Jensen's inequality, so that LogE[(exp(tX)] >= E[log(exp(tX)) = E[tX] = tE[X] = tmx.
So the first problem was solved.

I think I stuck here, so I have two questions:
(1) was I on the right path to solve the first problem?
(2) how should I proceed to solve the second problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please tag as [tag:self-study] and read its wiki! Then, you can use $\LaTeX$ on this site, please do so, your question will be easier to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll take the limit of the expression and apply [L'hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20more%20specifically%20calculus,be%20easily%20evaluated%20by%20substitution.):

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\log M_X(t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{M_X'(t)}{M_X(t)}=\frac{M'_X(0)}{M_X(0)}=\frac{\mathbb E[X]}{1}=mx$$

P.S. Please use $\LaTeX$ as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @gunes! Could you please elaborate on the part after your first equal sign? I am still confused about how it was obtained.

Comment: just differentiated both numerator and denominator separately as the l’hopital rule requires